# Issue with adjusting CAST in a calculation (precision)

Tags: sql

I believe it should be an easy fix for someone who is good at casting. I appreciate your help.

My calculation is :

```
CAST(SUM(p.QTY) / SUM (r.QTY) AS decimal (5,2)) AS 'Forecast Accuracy'

p.QTY - Forecast Demand

r.QTY - Last Week Actual
```

Example

```
p.QTY = 2596

r.QTY = 2504
```

Therefore my calculation is

```
2596/2504 = 1.04
```

But I have 1.00 as a result

There is an issue with precision I believe. Does someone know how I can adjust the so that the 4 is not dropped?

Comment: Use `round()` instead

Comment: @drum won't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet `p.QTY` and `r.QTY` are both integers.

The trick is an integer divided by another integer is *always*... still in an integer. You try to account for this when you cast to decimal, but by then it's already too late. At the time of the division operation we were still in integer land, where `2596` divided by `2504` is *exactly* `1`. No  more no less. Casting the integer `1` to numeric(5,2) just gets you `1.00`.

You can fix it like this:

```
CAST(SUM(p.QTY) / (1.00 * SUM (r.QTY)) AS decimal (5,2)) AS 'Forecast Accuracy'
```

This adds an extra multiplication step which forces an implicit cast *before* the division. Now we have an integer divided by a numeric, and *that* can give us meaningful results.

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc021521b689bad13af0ca90f203c04b

Comment: thank you!! That's exactly what I need!